# how to fit pdf page in entire view

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, sqlite, nsxmlparser

i read pdf files and also displayed, the code is like this:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
```

{

```
NSLog(@"the layer  height %d, %d,%d ,%d",layer.bounds.size.width,layer.bounds.size.height,layer.bounds.origin.x,layer.bounds.origin.y);


int c=[currentPage intValue]+1;
NSLog(@"drawing started");



if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([self interfaceOrientation])){
    layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocumentRef, c);

    NSLog(@"draw layer");
    CGSize pageSize = [kbDataSource pageSize];
    GLogInfo(@"the page ize we are getting in draw layer is %@ ",NSStringFromCGSize(pageSize));
    //CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    CGSize aspectFitSize = [self getPageFitSizeOfSize:pageSize inSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height- __TOP_BRANDING_BAR_HEIGHT)];
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));



    GLogDebug(@"aspect fitsize of image to %@", NSStringFromCGSize(aspectFitSize));
    NSLog(@"layer bounds are:%@  %@ ",NSStringFromCGSize(layer.bounds.size),NSStringFromCGPoint(layer.bounds.origin));
    NSLog(@"page size of the book is:%@",NSStringFromCGSize(pageSize));
    CGFloat aspectRatio=pageSize.width/pageSize.height;
/*  
    if (aspectRatio>0.5 && aspectRatio<=0.74) {
        NSLog(@"aspect ratio is between 0.5 and 0.74");
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx,-110 ,layer.bounds.size.height+100);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.28,-1.22);
    }
    else
        if (aspectRatio>0.74 && aspectRatio<1) {
            NSLog(@"aspect ratio is between 0.75 and 1");
            //CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -145,layer.bounds.size.height+85);
            //CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.4,-1.2);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -130,layer.bounds.size.height+75);
            CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.35,-1.18);

        }
        else if(aspectRatio>1) {
            NSLog(@"aspect ratio is above 1");
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx,-80,layer.bounds.size.height+80);
            CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.2,-1.2);
        }
        else {
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, layer.bounds.size.height);
            CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
        }*/


/*  
    CGFloat scalingRatio;


    if ((layer.bounds.size.width/pageSize.width)<((layer.bounds.size.height-41)/pageSize.height)){

     scalingRatio=layer.bounds.size.width/pageSize.width;

    }
    else {
        scalingRatio=(layer.bounds.size.height-41)/pageSize.height;
    }

    */
    CGRect cropBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);
    CGRect targetRect = layer.bounds;
    CGFloat xScale = targetRect.size.width / cropBox.size.width;
    CGFloat yScale = (targetRect.size.height-41) / cropBox.size.height;
    CGFloat scaleToApply = (xScale < yScale) ? xScale : yScale;

    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, -41+layer.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    NSLog(@"the crop box values are %@",NSStringFromCGRect(cropBox));
    NSLog(@"the crop box values are %f",cropBox.origin.x);

    NSLog(@"the scaleToApply is %f",scaleToApply);
    NSLog(@"the view bounds are %@",[self.view description]);

    if (scaleToApply == yScale)
        CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100, -150));
    else
        CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-180, -260)); //evans
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToApply, scaleToApply));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));
    //
    //CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToApply, scaleToApply));


    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh); 
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(ctx, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, myPageRef);
    //CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

    [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
    [loadingIndicator1 stopAnimating];
    [loadingIndicator2 stopAnimating];

}
```

it reads & displays pdf exactly, but problem is,it is not fit to entire view for each pdf,is there any modification or correction need in my code.please post some suggestions  and comments. thank you!!!

Comment: You can see the link,I think this may be useful for you--[link text](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF109)

Comment: can you give the answer for the modified code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display PDF on iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722526/display-pdf-on-ipad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate what scale values you need for the page to fit your view. Then put the proper values in your

```
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
```

call.

Comment: @ajay, were you able to write method to calculate the scale values that works in both orientation modes? If so can you please post it as an update in your question? Thanks!

Comment: @Flash84x it is normally a ratio of your page dimensions and the view/frame dimensions where you want to display it, where 100% = 1.0. Should be fairly easy to calculate.

Comment: Yeah, it is a simple calculation that I had figured out but for a reason I don't completely understand yet, passing that scale value to `CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, scale, -scale);` results in some undesired results. I had to use `CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale));`

Comment: hi all i modified some code can you please give me some more information.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634331/problem-with-rendering-pdf-on-the-entire-screen-of-pdf