# problem with rendering pdf on the entire screen of pdf

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Hi all I tried in many ways to print a pdf according with the size of the pdf book.i also searched in many links and many codes like apple codes,github and many such type of sites but no use.  This question is duplicate of many questions and answers but still i didN't get exact result.my code is looking like this

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
  {
  if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([self interfaceOrientation])){
      layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
      myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocumentRef, c);

  ```
  CGSize pageSize = [kbDataSource pageSize];
  GLogInfo(@"the page ize we are getting in draw layer is %@ ",NSStringFromCGSize(pageSize));
  //CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

  CGSize aspectFitSize = [self getPageFitSizeOfSize:pageSize inSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height- __TOP_BRANDING_BAR_HEIGHT)];
  CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));



  GLogDebug(@"aspect fitsize of image to %@", NSStringFromCGSize(aspectFitSize));
  NSLog(@"layer bounds are:%@  %@ ",NSStringFromCGSize(layer.bounds.size),NSStringFromCGPoint(layer.bounds.origin));
  NSLog(@"page size of the book is:%@",NSStringFromCGSize(pageSize));
  CGFloat aspectRatio=pageSize.width/pageSize.height;
      CGRect cropBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);
  CGRect targetRect = layer.bounds;
  CGFloat xScale = targetRect.size.width / cropBox.size.width;
  CGFloat yScale = (targetRect.size.height-41) / cropBox.size.height;
  CGFloat scaleToApply = (xScale < yScale) ? xScale : yScale;

  CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, -41+layer.bounds.size.height);
  CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
  NSLog(@"the crop box values are %@",NSStringFromCGRect(cropBox));
  NSLog(@"the crop box values are %f",cropBox.origin.x);

  NSLog(@"the scaleToApply is %f",scaleToApply);
  NSLog(@"the view bounds are %@",[self.view description]);

  if (scaleToApply == yScale)
      CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100, -150));
  else
      CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-180, -260)); 
  CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToApply, scaleToApply));
  CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));


  CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh); 
  CGContextSetRenderingIntent(ctx, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
  CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, myPageRef);
  ```

  }

I pasted all the code which i tried in drawlayer. I gave many random numbers to fit the page entire screen finally i got only for Eight books(pdfs).

My goal is to print any pdf with the entire ipad screen covering.
my result is getting  only for few pdfs.can any one tell me the exact reason why it is happening and also tell me exact code to print the pdf to the entire screen of ipad.

thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Pages in PDF files don't have a standard size. And since you are computing the scale to retain the correct aspect ratio, not all of your PDF files will take up the entire screen.

Based on your code above, you can make all PDF files fit the entire screen by changing

```
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToApply, scaleToApply));
```

to

```
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(xScale, yScale));
```

This will screw up the aspect ratio, though.

Comment: hi Altealice, I tried with the above line what you have mentioned but it is not at all helpful for my solution.i posted my new code.

Comment: same problem not working for all the pdfs.some rendering very well and some pages are not rendering entire screen.

Comment: It's rather impossible to fix "not working for all pdfs" over the internet. PDF files vary in ways too many to fathom. You'd have to investigate further and give more meaningful information.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the UIDocumentInteractionController to display the PDF?  It would be much easier then trying to render the PDF the way you are?  I have used UIDocumentInteractionController on several instances to preview PDFs, word docs, powerpoints, etc.

Check it out [HERE.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

This may give you what you need (Fill the whole screen with the PDF).  It will also allow you to print the document and open it in another app if needed...

Comment: can you please post some more details and samples.

Comment: Thank you Geoff Baum it's working fine but the functionality of my app have to change if i use UIDocumentInteractionController.so can u please tell me how to render with drawLayer.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to do it with drawLayer.  Just thought I would throw up an alternative...

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to read a PDF in iPhone/iPad: 1.Take one UIwebView (name:pdfView). 2.Give Iboutlet connection to it & Delegate it to FilesOwner 3.In Viewdidload

[self.pdfView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ObjC" ofType:@"pdf"]]]];

4.ObjC.pdf should be in resource folder..                                                   Now to Fit the pdf page of different size to the screen of the iPad just open respective .xib file then go to inspector of UIwebView then web view attributes and there tick mark scales page to fit option.